# INSERT INTO vehicles_summary (id, summary) VALUES (1, '{}');- what is {} in this?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I want to know what is {} that is been added in the table, and how is this done. This code has to be used using nodejs

The code from where it is fetching data is as follows,
but how it is adding data in that table is mystery.

```
  exports.index = function(req, res) {
    var db, q;
    db = req.db;
    q = db.query();
    q.select(['summary']);
    q.from('vehicles_summary');
    q.where('id=?', 1);
    return q.single(function(err, vehiclesSummary) {
      var filterObjects, summary;
      if (err != null) {
        return res.json(err);
      }
      summary = JSON.parse(vehiclesSummary.summary);
      filterObjects = JSON.parse(req.query.filter || '[]');
      if ((filterObjects != null ? filterObjects.length : void 0) > 0) {
        summary = filterVehicles(filterObjects, summary);
        console.log('-------------||||||||||||||||||||||--------------');
        console.log(summary);
      }
      return res.json(err, summary);
    });
  };
```

Comment: Could you add database what you use in the description and in a tag?

Comment: @galkin postgres

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're writing to some sort of database here, as this looks like a SQL insert statement.  In that case, 1 is your id, and {} is a representation of an empty object which is your summary.  You can add properties to it if you want, using regular JSON.

Eg: `{foo: bar}` would assign value bar to property foo on your object.  You're essentially just storing a serialized object as JSON.

Comment: Hi, yea that is right. but how the value is assigned is a mystery here.....
vehicles_summary is the table name, and it is taking values from another table, but it is taking only values where the boolean value is true...
There is no update or any other statement used in nodejs code

Comment: Do you mind posting the other code then?  The one snippet you have in the title isn't actually Javascript; it's just a SQL insert statement.  There is no mysterious value getting assigned here, the values being inserted are hard-coded right in the SQL as id: 1, and summary: {}.

Comment: Yup i have posted @istrupin